# Computing the Lebesgue Integral of $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\; d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am trying to compute the Lebesgue integral of $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\; d\mu$. I know that if a function $f$ is bounded on some set $X$ and is continuous almost everywhere on $X$, then the Lebesgue integral is equivalent to the Riemann integral.

Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is continuous almost everywhere on $X$ and is unbounded at $x=0$, I am not sure if the Lebesgue integral is equivalent to the Riemann integral here. However, I know that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is bounded *almost* *everywhere* on $[0, 1]$. Does this mean that I can use the Riemaan integral to compute the Lebesgue integral? If not, how else can I compute the Lebesgue integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $[0, 1]$?

Comment: How is ${1 \over \sqrt{x}}$ bounded almost everywhere?

Comment: On any interval $[\epsilon,1]$ The Lebesgue and Riemann integrals are the same, and the improper Riemann integral exists on $[0,1]$. What can you conclude about Lebesgue integrability on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Show that the integral is the limit of integrals $\int_\epsilon^1$ and you can use Riemann integration to compute the $\epsilon$ version.

Comment: @copper.hat I am not sure if this is correct, but I was thinking that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is bounded everywhere on $(0, 1]$, so it bounded almost everywhere on $[0, 1]$ when I wrote that part of my post.

Comment: That is not true. Think about what you are saying.

Comment: @copper.hat The only thing I can think of is that the function is not bounded on the point $x=0$. I'd really appreciate it if you could elaborate a bit on why I was wrong in my previous comment. I am new to Measure Theory. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with measure theory. A function $f$  is bounded on a set $A$ if there is some $B$ such that $|f(x)| \le B$ for all $x \in A$. Here $f(x) = {1 \over \sqrt{x}}$, $A=(0,1]$. There is no $B$ such that $|f(x)| \le B$ for all $x \in A$. You can remove sets of measure zero and this won't change here.

Comment: @copper.hat Pardon me for dragging this. Isn't $[0, 1] \setminus (0, 1] = \{0\}$ a set of measure $0$? So, when we remove this set of measure $0$ from consideration, isn't $f$ bounded everywhere on $(0, 1]$, which is the same as saying that it is bounded almost everywhere on $[0, 1]$?

Comment: No, given any number $B$, $f({1 \over B^2}) = B$, so it cannot be bounded on $(0,1]$!

Comment: Yes, $\{0\}$ is a set of measure zero, but that is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(L)\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(L)\int_{1/n}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(R)\int_{1/n}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx\\
&=\cdots,
\end{align*}
here $(L)$ and $(R)$ denote the Lebesgue and Riemann integrals repsectively, the first equality comes from Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: I find this very clever, thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain how you know that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is Borel-measurable on $[0, 1]$? (I think it is required to be Borel-measurable for the Lebesgue integral to be defined.)

Comment: Okay, use the monotonicity goes through.

Comment: The issue is that this function is monotonically decreasing on any given $[a, b] \subset [0, 1]$. It is not defined at $x=0$. It wouldn't be valid to say that this function is monotonically decreasing on $[0, 1]$, right? What am I missing?

Comment: The trick is as follows: $1/\sqrt{x}$ is Borel on $(0,1]$. But joining to a singleton ($\{0\}$) does not affect that being Borel since $\{0\}$ is a closed set. You may define any value at $x=0$.

Comment: I want to make sure that I am understanding this correctly. Am I correct in thinking that since $f(\{0\})$ is a singleton, and hence a closed set, that $f(\{0\})$ is a Borel set, and so $f$ is Borel measurable on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Actually I am saying the domain, $\{0\}$, not $\{f(0)\}$. The Borel property is to test the pre-image $f^{-1}(G)$, which lies in the domain.